# How can one debug imagent issues?

Tags: macos, apple-id, messages, facetime

I have just upgraded to OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion and am attempting to use Facetime and iMessage.  Upon entering my Apple ID into the respective applications and attempting to sign in, I receive the following error message:

> The server encountered an error processing registration.  Please try again later.

Whilst I assume that `imagent` proceeded beyond the authentication stage (as providing incorrect credentials results in a different error message), I am unable to ascertain exactly what went wrong.  I cannot find any log file (nor any option to enable logging) that shines light on the subject.  **Is it possible to audit `imagent` activity?**

I have found various suggestions, some of which appear to have worked for others:

1. Force quit the `imagent` process;
2. Reset `/etc/hosts` to default state;
3. Enable `ntp`;
4. Fix permissions and/or delete `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imagent.plist`;
5. Delete certain Apple-issued certificates from the user's login keychain;
6. Use Google's public DNS resolvers;
7. Disable all firewalls and packet filters;
8. Delete the contents of `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`;
9. Reset NVRAM/PRAM;
10. Reboot.

I have tried all of the above, with no improvement.

I have tried using two different Apple IDs: one a simple MobileMe account (ending `@me.com`) that has been transferred to iCloud; the other an old .Mac address (ending `@mac.com`) with which additional non-Apple email addresses have been associated and verified.  The computer is connected to iCloud with the former account; and I have previously used the latter account successully with Facetime on the same computer (when running Lion) and with iMessage on my iPhone and iPad.

I am at a loss to understand how I should proceed.  Whilst I would be grateful for any suggestion that fixes the problem, I would be far more grateful for a canoncial answer that describes how `imagent` issues can be debugged in the future: e.g. how to enable logging or similar.

Comment: I have the same problem and so far found no solution.

Comment: Do you mind editing the question's title a bit? I'm sure that many people will google this problem by merely using something like **[this](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=The+server+encountered+an+error+processing+registration&oq=The+server+encountered+an+error+processing+registration&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.520.520.0.850.1.1.0.0.0.0.87.87.1.1.0...0.0...1c.CW167a6oPRg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=6c7790a71c61b51c&biw=1375&bih=783=)**. Then this question only pops up on the second page.

Comment: I'd prefer for the title to contain the error message *"The server encountered an error processing registration."* as well - hoping that this will get ranked higher by google. This question got answered! More people should get to see this post.

Comment: I've started a discussion about this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5591236#5591236).

Comment: I guess it would help to put "The server encountered an error processing registration. Please try again later." in the title. It's a more or less "popular" string in the Google search field :-).

Comment: I think it would not be correct to focus on this particular issue (i.e. "error processing registration"), as my question was really about how to fix any `imagent` in the future; moreover, I don't feel any of the solutions have sufficiently explained what the problem was in this case to guarantee success for others who are seeking to rectify the same issue.  I'm therefore of the opinion that a change of title would be misleading, but it's not something over which I'll lose any sleep if others wish to make the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the file

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist
```

and after a reboot the error

```
The server encountered an error processing registration. Please try again later.
```

was gone (Mac OS X creates a new 'NetworkInterfaces.plist' file during the boot process).

The file

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist
```

contains informations about the network interfaces, it looks like the upgrade from 10.7 to 10.8 broke something (at least on my system).

'imagent' itself has no *debug option* but you can try tools like

```
dtruss
```

or the

```
Instruments.app
```

to monitor the program. Instruments.app is part of XCode and a GUI to dtruss.

Or you can monitor the network traffic between imagent and the server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; however it sadly did not work for me: indeed, the newly-created `NetworkInterfaces.plist` is identical to the old one.

Comment: Remove all files inside the folder /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/ (before you do this create a backup of the folder) and then reset the NVRAM (This URL http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379 explains how you do this).

Comment: Another idea is to check if something blocks the ports of the 'imagent', do you use programs (IP-Filter) like 'Hands Off!' or 'Little Snitch'? An IP-filter maybe blocks the outgoing connection. And turn of the Mac OS X 'Firewall", just to make sure that nothing blocks the ports of the 'imagent'.

Comment: Thank you for your further suggestions; however sadly none of them have worked for me.  I deleted all files and folders in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`, disabled my EFI password (couldn't find a way to reset PRAM with it enabled), reset PRAM, reenabled my EFI password, rebooted, disabled both OS X firewall and Little Snitch packet filtering... but I still get the same "error processing registration".  Grateful for any thoughts you might have on *how to debug* what is happening, rather than stabs in the dark at potential solutions.

Comment: Check 

http://imfreedom.org/wiki/IMessage

for informations about how iMessage works and maybe you can use the tools I mentioned above to monitor the programs.

It looks like that 'applepushserviced' is responsible for the connection, you can turn on debug logs for this program (how you do this is described in the link).

I saw that 'applepushserviced' has a keychain

'/Library/Keychains/applepushserviced.keychain'

you can check if this keychain is maybe corrupted on your system.

Comment: You can add as #11 :-) to remove /Library/Preferences/com.apple.applepushserviced.plist (dont forget the reboot :-)) it contains some unique Machine identifiers…

Comment: Thank you, the `Instruments.app` tip was brilliant.  I monitored file activity and saw a lot of writing to my login keychain; I then deleted (again) all Apple related certificates and keys, killed `imagent` and tried again - success!  Of course, it would be nice to have a deeper understanding of what was going on, but it looks like this isn't possible without further help from Apple.

Comment: Me gusta this answer! Removing `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist` and rebooting totally worked! Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you and I agree a deeper understanding would be nice when you search for 'The server encountered an error processing registration. Please try again later.' you can see that we are no alone with this problem :-).